# Dealing with xlsm in Power Automate

Tags: xlsx, power-automate, xlsm

Is there a way to retrieve the most updated file and retrieve content from it in a Power Automate flow? Currently, Power Automate doesn't support the xlsm format, so I'm exploring an alternative approach. My idea is to use a macro in Excel to copy and create a new file in xlsx format. The new file will always have the same name and will replace the previous version (using the "kill" method in VBA). The files are stored in SharePoint.

Since the file is constantly being replaced, the table ID keeps changing. I want to create a flow that can retrieve the table and data from the files, but I need a method to always access the most updated file. Is there a way to achieve this in Power Automate?

To be honest, I attempted to use Get Files (Properties only) and trying to put the ID in the list rows in a table but I am confusing how to write the expression and really out of idea in the flow.

Comment: Yep, look at Office Scripts. Is perfect for your requirement.

Comment: I wish to send email based on condition (that's why I need to always extract the latest data from the xlsx file), do office scripts support this kind of feature similar to Power Automate?

Comment: Read up on it, it's built into PowerAutomate ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 files with the same name, 1 with XLSM and 1 is XLSX what i did is first select the XLSX file and then change the extension to XLSM in power automate. It works fine.

Comment: The content in xlsm still can be retrieved? But how did you do that? Can you attach some screenshots for that? Thanks!